# How to compare char* and NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hi I am comparing UserName(char*) from database and UserName(NSString*) from UITextField. How to do this.
Following is my code

```
if ([UserName isEqual:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]) {

    NSLog(@"User Already Exists.");
    flag = YES;
    return;
}
```

But it never goes into loop though I give same UserName as in Database.

Answer (score 9):

Assume following is the *NSString* you have.

```
NSString *userName = @"SomeOnesName";
```

Get the C-String from DB and convert it to *NSString*.

```
NSString *userNameFromDB = [NSString stringWithCString:sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now the comparison.

```
if ([userName isEqualToString:userNameFromDB]) {
```

Comment: You are ignoring potential encoding issues.

Comment: That's much better :)  as long as it is in the database in UTF-8

Comment: If you have database in UTF-8, you can also use `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]` for converting const char* to NSString