# Compare char array with string in iOS program

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compare char* and NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065537/how-to-compare-char-and-nsstring)

If I have:

```
char XYZ[256]="";
```

how can I compare this char array with another string (e.g. "testing") in an iOS Objective-C program?

Comment: I think my account was suspended to post new question due to I posted this question. 
I read the FAQ, it asked me to rework the wrong question, I actually don't know what should I do if I want to re-enable my account, the question was asked and answered already, I know I posted the wrong question, but I just don't have a chance to fix it. After a few days since last login, my account is locked... would you please help me to let me know how can I reenable my account, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [strcmp](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strcmp.3.html)

```
char XYZ[256] = "";
char *string = "some other string";

int order = strcmp(XYZ, string);
```

> **RETURN VALUES**
>   The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer greater than, equal to, or less than 0, according as the string s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the string s2.  The comparison is done using unsigned characters, so that `\200' is greater than`\0'.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore D: "Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'const char *' is disallowed with ARC"

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert them up to NSString, this makes a lot overhead, but brings your string to Objective-C object:

```
char XYZ[256] = "";
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:XYZ length:strlen(XYZ) encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
NSString *testing = @"testing";
if ([testing compare:s] == NSOrderedSame) {
    NSLog(@"They are hte same!");
}
```

Note that `strcmp` is A LOT faster!

Answer (score 0):

Just because it is iOS doesnt mean that you cannot "#include" string.h and use "strcmp" (now as stated above).

The alternative would be to create a new NSString and compare it using a comperable iOS Objective-C call:

```
NSString myString = [NSString stringWithCString:XYZ encodingNSASCIIStringEncoding];

if(YES == [myString isEqualToString:@"testing"]){
    // Perform Code if the strings are equal
}else{
    // Perform Code if the strings are NOT equal
}
```